# scrapy, how to parse AJAX response from asp.net page on POST

Tags: asp.net, scrapy

I want to look through the companies at: https://www.greg.gg/webCompSearch.aspx

I know that the asp.net form needs certain parameters that can be extracted. When sending a POST in scrapy as `FormRequest` I also get a response with the additional data. My problem is that it is only partially html, see:

```
1|#||4|1890|updatePanel|ctl00_updPanel|
    <br />
        <div id="login">
            <div id="ctl00_pnlLogin" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;ctl00_btnLogin&#39;)">
```

So the question is how I could parse the HTML properly.

Here is the minimal scrapy spider as reference:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy

class GgTestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gg_test'
    allowed_domains = ['www.greg.gg']
    base_url = 'https://www.greg.gg/webCompSearch.aspx'
    start_urls = [base_url]
    custom_settings = {
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        # grep ASP.NET elements out of response
        EVENTVALIDATION = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]/@value').extract_first()
        VIEWSTATE = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]/@value').extract_first()
        PREVIOUSPAGE = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="__PREVIOUSPAGE"]/@value').extract_first()
        response.meta['fdat'] = {
            '__EVENTTARGET': '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
            '__VIEWSTATE': VIEWSTATE,
            '__PREVIOUSPAGE': PREVIOUSPAGE,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': EVENTVALIDATION,
            '__ASYNCPOST': "true",
            'ctl00$ScriptManager2': "ctl00$cntPortal$updPanel|ctl00$cntPortal$btnSearch",
            'ctl00$cntPortal$radSearchType': "radStartsWith",
            'ctl00$cntPortal$chkPrevNames': "on",
            'ctl00$cntPortal$ddlRegister': "0",
            'ctl00$cntPortal$btnSearch': "Search"
        }

        # id to search
        response.meta['fdat']['ctl00$cntPortal$txtCompRegNum'] = "1"

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            headers={
                'Referer': self.base_url,
                'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true',
            },
            formdata=response.meta['fdat'],
            meta={'fdat': response.meta['fdat']},
            callback=self._parse_items,
        )

    def _parse_items(self, response):

        company_item = response.xpath(
            '//input[contains(@id, "ctl00$cntPortal$grdSearchResults$ctl")]/@value').extract()

        print "no data:", response.request.headers, response.meta['fdat'], company_item, response.xpath('/')
        response.meta['fdat']['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]/@value').extract()
        response.meta['fdat']['__VIEWSTATE'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]/@value').extract()
        response.meta['fdat']['__PREVIOUSPAGE'] = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="__PREVIOUSPAGE"]/@value').extract()

        # give as input to form (POST) to get redirected
        for i in company_item:
            response.meta['fdat']['ctl00$ScriptManager2'] = 'ctl00$cntPortal$updPanel|{0}'.format(i)
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                url=self.base_url,
                formdata=response.meta['fdat'],
                meta={'company_extra_id': response.meta['company_extra_id']},
                callback=self._parse_company,
            )

    def _parse_company(self, response):
        pass
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I changed the title of the question from how to get the full HTML like displayed in the browser to how to actually parse the partial HTML that is returned by the POST.

Comment: it is possible that on a post request , source website is only sending partial HTML and updating what is required on page with AJAX call, you should fireup your choice of browser and monitor network call to understand what is happening

Comment: I saw the XHR request before in the browser network tools but didn't know partial HTML ca also be interpreted, only knew about JSON. Anyways is there a recommended way to parse the partial HTML? I updated the question.

Comment: you should be able to use .xpath and .css on response by default  if not convert response to Selector object http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=text#using-selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=text#constructing-selectors)

```
response_data = scrapy.Selector(text=response.body)
# this will give you selector object 
# you should be able to use .xpath and .css on response_data
```

Comment: okay it was that easy ... I thought it didn't work initially but my xpath query was just wrong. It added the tags like this `<html><body><p>1|#||4|1890|updatePanel|c'>`. I'm sorry to have wasted your time.